# 'Official' way to install some packages in Debian 10 that are in Testing?

Tags: debian

I looked at the most popular answer in [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/22414/how-can-i-run-debian-stable-but-install-some-packages-from-testing) thread, but people said it broke their system. Is there no 'official', safe way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

None aside from a very limited number of packages in backports. If you're concerned with your system reliability use a more appropriate distro. E.g. Ubuntu LTS contains much fresher packages and has a very long support period and allows to use HWE, i.e. much newer kernels and other perks.

Answer (score 0):

Break the system or not that depends on the package and on your system but it is generally bad practice to do. The safest way is to use backports (check https://backports.debian.org/) but you will not find every package there and it is not 100% safe (but still the safest!).

You can also check https://wiki.debian.org/DontBreakDebian in addition debian reference https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-reference/ for some tips regarding the package management specially the package management from different sources of archives (section 2.7.2)